# Trying to find the longest induced path using DFS in a graph

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search, longest-path

here is the code I am currently applying that is a DFS algorithm in order to find the longest induced path (the longest 'snake') of a graph:

```
def dfs(node, adj, dp, vis): 
    # Mark as visited
    vis[node] = True
    #print(vis[adj[node][0]])
    # Traverse for all its children
    for i in range(0, len(adj[node])):
        # If not visited
        if vis[adj[node][i]]==False:
            dfs(adj[node][i], adj, dp, vis) 
        # Store the max of the paths
        dp[node] = max(dp[node], [node] + dp[adj[node][i]], key=lambda x: len(x))
    print(dp[node])
        
        
# Function that returns the longest path 
def findLongestPath(adj, n): 
    # Dp array 
    dp = [[x] for x in range(n)]
    # Visited array to know if the node 
    # has been visited previously or not 
    vis = [False] * (n)
    # Call DFS for every unvisited vertex 
    for i in range(n):
        if vis[i]==False: 
            dfs(i, adj, dp, vis) 
    # Traverse and find the maximum of all dp[i]
    return max([dp[i] for i in range(n)], key=lambda x: len(x))


# The adjacency list of the graph
adj = [[1, 4], [0, 2], [1, 3, 4], [2, 4], [0, 2, 3]]

final = findLongestPath(adj, len(adj))
print(final)
```

The main issue I assume remains in my DFS algorithm:

```
def dfs(node, adj, dp, vis): 

    # Mark as visited
    vis[node] = True
    #print(vis[adj[node][0]])
    # Traverse for all its children
    for i in range(0, len(adj[node])):
        # If not visited
        if vis[adj[node][i]]==False:
            dfs(adj[node][i], adj, dp, vis) 
        # Store the max of the paths
        dp[node] = max(dp[node], [node] + dp[adj[node][i]], key=lambda x: len(x))
    print(dp[node])
```

I tried to print all the longest paths starting from each node at the end, as you can see print(dp[node]), and here are the outputs:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Although this is nice, seeing all the longest paths starting from each node, but this is not what I wanted as I want the longest **induced** paths. Such as the longest induced path for this graph, that one example might be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Instead of the one, I got in my output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Node 4 is not included because if we include 4, there will be an edge from 0-4 which wouldn't make an induced path.

Is there a way to modify my Dfs algorithm that would output only the longest **induced** paths instead of all the longest paths? What should I change in my Dfs function? Thanks!

Comment: You say "the longest induced paths so that there are no repeats of each node" - however, that's not what an induced path is? An longest induced path on a graph is a longest sequence of vertices from the graph so that adjacent vertices in the path are adjacent in the graph and no two vertices in the path are adjacent to another in the graph unless they are connected in the path. (i.e. a the longest 'snake' in the graph that never gets within distance 1 of itself but always mantains a distance of 2 or more)

Comment: @Grismar Sorry, I wasn't precise with my wording. What I meant was the longest induced path that is e.g. in this case [0, 1, 2, 3], you don't want [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] which actually forms a circle.

Comment: @Grismar Do you maybe have any ideas on how to modify this in a way that gives the longest induced paths in the DFS?

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comment it's not clear if you correctly understand what a 'longest induced path' is, so here's an example I wrote that can get you either the first longest induced path found or all of them (which is convenient to get a sense of what it is):

```
def longest_induced_path(adj, all_longest=False):
    def _dfs(node, path, off_limits):
        yield (path := path + [node])
        for next_node in adj[node]:
            if next_node not in off_limits:
                yield from _dfs(next_node, path, off_limits | set(adj[node]))

    def _first():
        lp = []
        for n in range(len(adj)):
            for p in _dfs(n, [], {n}):
                if len(p) > len(lp):
                    lp = p
        return lp

    def _all():
        lp = []
        for n in range(len(adj)):
            for p in _dfs(n, [], {n}):
                if not lp or len(p) > len(lp[0]):
                    lp = [p]
                elif len(p) == len(lp[0]):
                    lp.append(p)
        return lp

    return _all() if all_longest else _first()


def main():
    adj = [{1, 4}, {0, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 4}, {0, 2, 3}]

    print(longest_induced_path(adj))
    print(longest_induced_path(adj, all_longest=True))


main()
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 4, 3], [3, 2, 1, 0], [3, 4, 0, 1]]
```

The graph looks something like this:

```
0 - 4 - 3
|   | /
1 - 2
```

So, you can see that it finds every longest path P in the graph G so that:

- each vertex A that's a neighbour of any vertex B in P, is also the neighbour of B in G;
- no two vertices A and B in P are neighbours in G unless they are also neighbours in P.

As an example of that second constraint in action(making P a longest induced path): `[0, 1, 2, 4, 3]` is not an induced path, because both `0` and `4` are in it, but they are neighbours in G, while they are not neighbours in P, which the constraint forbids.

Of course, if you only require the result of `_first()`, you can just simplify your code - I included `_all()` and the option to call it to provide the example of all longest paths.

A different (if perhaps harder to read) version of `_dfs`:

```
    def _dfs(node, path, off_limits):
        if adj[node].issubset(off_limits):
            yield path + [node]
        else:
            for next_node in adj[node] - off_limits:
                yield from _dfs(next_node, path + [node], off_limits | set(adj[node]))
```

It's arguable simpler and prevents more calls to itself, but performs almost identical to the other implementation when timed. It's possible that for more complicated graphs one wins out over the other, but you get to find out which yourself.

Edit: updated initial value for `off_limits` to `{n}` instead of `{set}` to avoid cyclical return values.

Note: when using a version of Python before 3.8, you want this as the first lines of `_dfs`:

```
        path = path + [node]
        yield path
```

Comment: Thanks, Grismar for providing the solution. However, I tested with another graph (a different adjacency list) using your code: [[1], [0, 3], [], [1]]. And the output for print(longest_induced_path(adj) is: [0, 1, 0]. Is this right? Is this an induced path since it starts at node 0 but also ends up at node 0? Wouldn't this be a circle?

Comment: Since [0, 1, 0] is a circle, does this mean an induced path can also be an induced circle?

Comment: Sorry, also is there a way without using 'yield' or 'yield from'? I am on an older version of Python which doesn't support yield as it is giving me syntax error.

Comment: I think you mean 'induced cycle' - an induced cycle is very different from an induced path, because the end has to be the beginning, which of course means the next to last vertex needs to be a neighbour of the starting vertex - something the algorithm disallows. Of course, if you take an induced cycle and remove any two adjacent vertices, you get an induced path, but not the longest one (it could be, but it's not particularly likely)

Comment: `yield from` was introduced in Python 3.3 - if you need to use a Python version from before that, you should mention that in your question since it's generally a pretty bad idea and certainly not common. However, generators have been part of Python since early Python 2 versions, so you should be able to just loop over the generator and yield from the `for` loop - e.g. `for x in some_generator(): yield x` - which is the same as `yield from some_generator()` just a bit less efficient.

Comment: `yield` was introduced in Python 2.2, [it would appear](https://peps.python.org/pep-0255/) - if you're using a version of Python before that, you should *really* consider upgrading, that's positively ancient.

Comment: When I tested with another graph (a different adjacency list) using your code: [[1], [0, 3], [], [1]]. This gave me an induced circle instead of an induced path. So for this graph, the output for print(longest_induced_path(adj) is: [0, 1, 0] and this is not an induced path but an induced circle?

Comment: Also I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax ^ yield (path := path + [node])

Comment: Also for graph = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3]]. The program returns 2 instead of 1. So there must be something wrong within the program.

Comment: And I found the reason why it is giving me syntax error. It is because of your use of ':='. I have fixed this. But the problem still stands as for graph = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3]]. The longest induced path was supposed to be 1, but the program returned 2.

Comment: The walrus operator `:=` has been part of Python since 3.8 if memory serves - if you need answers for older versions of Python than the current version, you should always mention the version. Not using the walrus operator is generally trivial though. There was an error in the solution - instead of `set()` `off_limits` should of course have been initialised to `{n}`